# Link Between NAT VMSwitch and NetNat Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, virtual-machines, hyper-v, switch

Would really appreciate if someone can answer this for me it's been bugging me for a while. I've been going through documentation and articles on creating virtual nat switches and I have the process itself down OK. But there are some nuances I don't understand. The main one is something I stumbled upon in this article.

https://www.petri.com/using-nat-virtual-switch-hyper-v

When you create a new virtual NAT switch in powershell, you assign the host NIC an IP, prefix length, alias, etc. What confuses me is, when he performs this command:

```
New-NetNAT -Name “NATNetwork” -InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 192.168.0.0/24
```

It automatically applies that to "NATSwitch" but nowhere in the command does he specify on what switch to apply that configuration. My question is who the heck does Windows know where to apply that "New-NetNAT" configuration without being explicitly told to? I feel like this is going to cause problems in the future if I try to create more than one virtual switch. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the preceding command, he assigns an IP address of 192.168.0.1 to the virtual NIC that attaches to that switch. In the command that you showed, it sets the IP range for NAT to the same scope as as the new IP address (address 192.168.0.1 belongs to network 192.168.0.0/24).
If you create additional NAT switches, you only need to ensure that the new NAT network does not conflict with existing networks and that its corresponding vNIC's IP belongs to the network.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification that makes sense. Have a Happy New Year!